# no audio windows 8.1

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1

I screwed the sound on my laptop (Windows 8.1);

I installed the (I assume) wrong version of the realtek HDA drivers and now I have two copies of the audio device. I have tryed uninstalling the realtek drivers and deleting the audio devices, and the result is that windows detects the 2 devices again.

Now I have no audio service running because it says that there are duplicated entry points.

Any advice?

Comment: Use a [restore point](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zxue/archive/2012/03/09/windows-8-how-to-29-restore-system-to-a-previous-state-using-restore-point.aspx) to revert back to before you installed that driver.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

I kind of solved this;

I uninstalled my audio devices and installed the last realtek high definition audio codec. then rebooted and voilà, I had sound again.

Regretably, no HDMI audio (As before).